# How do I get permission to navigator.getusermedia via webview in cordoba?

Tags: android, cordova

I want to develop Android through cordova webview on the web made with HTML. However, cordova is not allowed in navigator.getusermedia. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request run-time permission to use the camera with [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin):

- Install diagnostic plugin to your project

  - `cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic`
- Install [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin to your project

  - `cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config`
- Add manifest entry for camera permission to your config.xml (see [Android permissions](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#android-permissions)):

  ```
  <platform name="android">
      <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
      </config-file>
  </platform>
  ```
- [Request camera authorization](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#requestcameraauthorization) at runtime:

  ```
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
      cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestCameraAuthorization(
          function(status){
              if(status == cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED){
                  // permission granted - use camera
                  var video = document.querySelector('video');

                  if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
                      navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {
                          video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                      }, function(e){
                          console.log("Error:" + e);
                      });
                  } else {
                      console.log("No media available");
                  }
              }else{
                  // permission denied - inform user
              }
          }, function(error){
              console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
          }, false
      );  
  }, false);
  ```

Comment: To add custom config with android your <widget> tag must have xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" - https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config/issues/24